# Using golang.org/x/time/rate to allow N requests per minute

Tags: go, rate-limiting

**What I want:**
A limiter which allows *n* requests per minute.

**What I tried:**

```
(somewhere during init procedure)

limiter = rate.NewLimiter(rate.Every(1*time.Minute/2), 2)
```

Then in the middleware of my HTTP server:

```
func (self *Router) limiterMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        if !limiter.Allow(){
            http.Error(responseWriter, "Too many requests", http.StatusTooManyRequests)
            return
        }

        next.ServeHTTP(responseWriter, request)
    })
}
```

This should, to my understanding, allow 2 requests per minute. Then I tried to send several requests, with the first two having 15s of pause in between, then roughly 1 request per second.

**Expectation:**

- first two requests work
- subsequent requests get HTTP429 until 1 minute has passed, and the first succeeding one is "cleared"
- one more request works
- subsequent requests get HTTP429 until 15s have passend, and the initial second request is"cleared"

**Actual result:**

```
22/10/31 14:02:31 access: 200 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:46 access: 200 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:47 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:48 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:49 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:50 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:51 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:52 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:53 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:54 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:55 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:56 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:57 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:58 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:02:59 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:00 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:01 access: 200 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:02 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:03 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:04 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:05 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:06 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:07 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:08 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:09 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:10 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:11 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:12 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:13 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:14 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:15 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:16 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:16 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:17 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:18 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:19 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:20 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:21 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:22 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:23 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:24 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:25 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:26 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:27 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:28 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:29 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:30 access: 429 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:32 access: 200 POST /some/path
22/10/31 14:03:33 access: 429 POST /some/path
```

You can see from the log that after the initial 2 requests, the third successful request happens after 30s. This means, that during 30s of uptime, 3 requests have succeeded, while it should only be 2. The fourth successful request happens again after 30s (60s in total).

If I set the bursts to 1, then initially only 1 request succeeds, and every 30s one more request can succeed.

So I am not sure how I should configure the limiter to achieve what I want (plain *n* requests per minute).

What am I doing wrong? Can this even be achieved using the built-in limiter, or do I need a different library for this task?

Comment: Limiter implements a token bucket. So your code essentially stipulates "(a) create a token bucket with capacity of 2, initially full, (b) add a new token to that bucket every 30 seconds, (c) if the bucket is empty do not allow the request". That matches the behaviour you're seeing - the first 2 tokens are depleted instantly, and then new tokens are added and consumed every 30s thereafter.

Comment: @nj_ Okay so this library is not able to do what I want to achieve? Do I need to get a sliding-window based limiter instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Limiter` implements a token bucket algorithm, which in essence feeds tokens at the stipulated interval.

You mentioned sliding window in a comment: I don't believe a "standard" implementations of sliding window for rate limiting will exactly match the behaviour you're after. The approach described under https://konghq.com/blog/how-to-design-a-scalable-rate-limiting-algorithm indicates weighting over fixed windows should be used, and I've seen this type approach implemented. That said, it's still not a bad approach to go for - a library like https://github.com/Narasimha1997/ratelimiter may handle this for you.

The behaviour you're describing seems to better match what is described as "sliding log" in the linked article, which you could look to implement, albeit with the caveats it describes in mind.

Comment: Actually, I should have mentioned, that the "2 requests per minute" is just for my current testing, when I wanted to check if I am using the limiter correctly.

My actual rate limiting will be more like 1000 requests per minute or something. In this case, as I understand it, the bucket gets refilled quicker, so I would see a different result.

I was just curious, because when I tried first with 10 requests per minute, it would allow 11 requests and block the 12th one, so I tried to find out if I have a bug, or the limiter is actually working this way. So I narrowed it down by trying 2/min.

Comment: So to clarify, I still don't fully understand how this works. Because when setting a burst != 1 the limiter will just allow more requests per interval than configured/intended, and when setting a burst of 1 it will just allow only one.

Comment: I don't get the same behaviour as you when configuring the standard limiter with `rate.NewLimiter(rate.Every(time.Minute/10), 10)` - if I send requests in rapid succession, I see 10 requests allowed, and the 11th is denied. To be clear, with this configuration, the way this works is: there are 10 tokens in the bucket initially, you can remove those tokens at _any_ rate. 1 new token is added every 6 seconds. If the number of tokens in the bucket exceed 10, they are discarded. So that is actually "burst of 10 requests, with 1 request permitted every 6 seconds thereafter if the burst is depleted"

Comment: With a 1000 request / minute goal in mind, I suspect you'll be fine with a sliding window type implementation. Maybe take a look at https://github.com/Narasimha1997/ratelimiter

Comment: I didnt fire the 10 requests instantly, but with a short delay instead (manual trigger in API testing tool, so maybe ~1s between requests). It still should not lead to the observed behaviour according to your explanation though.
I don't want to necessarily use a sliding window. I just need to protect my API with a rate limiter, and the most intuitive thing would be to say "allow XXXX requests per minute". This is why I tried the golang rate limiter, but I was unable to understand the output / judge if its working as intended, since it seems to not to work as intended.

Comment: So if I fire 10 requests with 1s pause, this would mean that during this time 1 new token is added to the bucket, and indeed 11 requests will be allowed. After 12s even a 12th request would be allowed. So actually instead of 10 per minute it will allow 10 + 60/6 = 20 requests. So it is my understanding that with the golang limiter it is not possible to configure a limiter which expresses a "XXXX requests per minute" limit. This might also be totally okay for my use cases, however I find it hard to judge whats going on and if the limit is applied correctly.

Comment: Indeed, I don't think it's strictly possible to use the stdlib limiter for "`X` requests per minute" unless `X` is exactly 1. To maybe put it differently: `rate.Every(time.Minute/10)` is _not_ telling the limiter to permit 10 requests per minute, it is telling it to allow 1 request every 6 seconds - that roughly equates to 10 requests a minute, but it's not the same thing - because the requests have to essentially be evenly spaced (6s apart) to get through. And the second argument which defines the bucket size/burst doesn't really help get towards a "`X` requests per minute" type setup either.